# how to calculate rms voltage value of PWM motor

Tags: voltage, motor, pwm, rms

My motor is of brushless type controlled by a PWM signal, it is three-phase synchronous.
I measured the three voltages of each phase and now I need to calculate the RMS value on all 3 phases.

[image]

Comment: So, why isn't the measured value what you need?

Comment: What did you measure them with? If it was measured with a true RMS multimeter (most multimeters are, except the super cheap ones), then the value you measured is your RMS value.

Comment: @Andyaka: I measured the three net voltages of each phase U1, U2 and U3 and now I want to calculate the total rms value votage.

Comment: @Felthry: I used 3 probes of voltages for each phase and chassis NI-compact

Comment: Are you saying you measured them with an oscilloscope? Most scopes have a built-in function to calculate RMS.

Comment: @Felthry Unfortunately it is not an oscilloscope we used the three probes with a chassis and application labview

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not understanding what you mean. Tony Stewart's answer below should answer your question, though.

Answer (score 2):

- for d=PWM duty cycle  for DC input \$ V_{rms}=d*V_{dc}\$ for each phase

assuming half bridge drive between Vdc and 0V

Averaging DMMs assume sine wave and measure peak and convert and for a sine wave \$V_{rms}= V_p/\sqrt{2}\$  so your results will be in error with PWM and DMM and true RMS meter or correction factors must be used.

Comment: Ps: The shape of the voltage curve of each phase is rectangular

Comment: how can I calculate the d (duty cycle)??

Comment: d= t(on)/t(cycle) *100%

Comment: I have U1 votage of RS, U2 voltage of SR and U3 voltage of TS. This values are obtained by experimental measurement. And now I want to calculate rms voltage value for RST and not for each phase because after that I wil calculate the power consumed by this motor. for exemple for the case of current I have I1 current phase R, I2 current phse S and I3 current phase T and Irms=sqrt(I1^2+I2^2+I3^2)/sqrt(3). Have any suggestion for the Urms?

Comment: Show schematic or simulation. Is desired end result Pd(Φ, t, avg,rms vs load)??  I cannot see your block diagram, hence no idea on your references.

Comment: I sent you the voltage curve fr one phase by mail

Comment: I posted PNG file above.  You can convert PWM to avg DC and then see average square wave frequency is 5 cycles in 0.1s or 50 Hz